# Learning Better Way of Doing It (Django Models)

Tags: python, django

I am doing Django and I have 4 models. District, Province, Schools and User. The District belongs to a Province, in the School model/table there are the foreign keys to which the school belong. In the User table, I have district, province and school foreign keys. these tuples were named province or district in the tables they are FKs. The error I was getting was a conflict and needed to add a **related_name**. I need someone to explain to me the value for related_name. From my reading, it is showing the table name, If the FK is in the Comments model then the related_name='comments'. In my case I have three FK in the User model so how do I manage this?

I hope this tries to explain my query.

Comment: Please suggest some meaningful title, SO is not only a place to solve immediate problems but to help future readers with their problems.

Comment: @SunderamDubey what would you rather the title be?

Comment: @StephenC the answer below is more understandable. The suggestion you gave was confusing because the related_name was map in a Map model. The below is clear enough. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 1):

`related_name` is used for reverse relations..

an Example of one: from a District Object, I want to get all of the students in the distinct

```py
districtObj.student_set.all()
# > Returns a list of Students

# format: {model}_set
```

Now you've got a conflict because `student_set` (the default) is taken, I'm not 100% **why** tbh, but it is.
Maybe someone smarter than me can explain..

Now that you know what you are setting, hopefully you can figure out a naming scheme..

Here's an Example: if you set Student.distinct's related name to 'students_in_district' you'd use it like:

```py
districtObj.students_in_district.all()
```